# Get the file name into the worksheet same as the order in the folder

Tags: excel, vba

I created a code to get the all the file names in the folder into a worksheet.I use this to check the accuracy of the file names(Please see the diagram below).

[image: Excel Worksheet Screen Shot]

When I click the macro file names of the destination folder appear under the system reports.Then I use some formulas to match the file names with "Actual Names" column and indicates it to the user.

There is an issue with my code that the order of the file names displaying in the the worksheet is changing day by day though the file names and the order of the files are same in the destination folder.

How do I solve this problem?

```
Sub GetFiles_Name()
 Dim x As String, y As Variant

 x = "D:\Reports\*"
 y = GetFileList(x)
   Select Case IsArray(y)
     Case True
       MsgBox UBound(y)
       Sheets("Cost").Range("H6:H11").Select
       Selection.ClearContents
       For i = LBound(y) To UBound(y)
        Sheets("Cost").Cells(i, 8).Rows("6").Value = y
    Next i
Case False
   MsgBox "No Matching Files Found!"
End Select
End Sub

Function GetFileList(FileSpec As String) As Variant

Dim FileArray() As Variant
Dim FileCount As Integer
Dim FileName As String

On Error GoTo NoFilesFound
FileCount = 0
FileName = Dir(FileSpec)
If FileName = "" Then GoTo NoFilesFound

Do While FileName <> ""
   FileCount = FileCount + 1
   ReDim Preserve FileArray(1 To FileCount)
   FileArray(FileCount) = FileName
   FileName = Dir()

Loop
GetFileList = FileArray
Exit Function

NoFilesFound:
 GetFileList = False
End Function
```

Comment: If you use an appropriate formula to check for a match then it wouldn't matter what order the file names are returned in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see several problems with your `Sub GetFiles_Name()`:

- The variable `y` is an array, but you're using it as if it was a variable on this line:

  ```
  Sheets("Cost").Cells(i, 8).Rows("6").Value = y
  ```

  When you do that, VBA will take the first element of the `y` array and use it in each column. Has your code actually ever worked as you show in your picture?
- By writing `Sheets("Cost").Range("H6:H11").ClearContents` you assume that your files will always be 6 (from 6 to 11). Is that really the case? I would rather use something more flexible (here I assume that `H5` corresponds to your `Actual Names` header column):

  ```
  Dim lastRow As Integer: lastRow = Sheets("Cost").Range("G5").End(xlDown).Row
  Sheets("Cost").Range("H6:H" & lastRow).ClearContents
  ```

  Also notice that you don't need to `.Select` first and then clear the `Selection`. You can directly `.ClearContents` on the range without selecting.
- Finally, in order not to be dependent on the order of the `System Reports` column files, you should look for each file and, if matched, just write it close to it. It would look like this:

  ```
     For i = LBound(y) To UBound(y)
      Set matched = Range("G6:G" & lastRow).Find(y(i), LookAt:=xlWhole) '<-- I assume "G" is the column with the file names moving in order
      If Not matched Is Nothing Then '<-- if I found the file in the list
          matched.Offset(0, 1) = y(i) '<-- put the file name in the adjacent column H
      End If
     Next i
  ```

Comment: firstly I really appreciate your assistance.
1)for the first question , answer would be Yes that I have made a mistake when uploading the code that  it should be `Sheets("Cost").Cells(i, 8).Rows("6").Value = y(i)` . Anything apart from that my code works well except the file order issue. And also I use only the ("H6:H11") there are a small no of files to be checked.



2) When I use the code you provided above, it displays me an error message object does not support this property or method by highlighting `matched.Offset(0, 1) = y(i)` line. Since I am new to the VBA, how do I solve this?

Comment: The object `matched` is by definition either a `Range` object (if something was found), or `Nothing` (if nothing was found). You can't get in that line if `matched` is `Nothing`, so I wouldn't expect such an error. I've tested the code on a sample data and it was working fine, when you click on "Debug" after the error and watch the variable `matched`, what do you see?

Comment: When I click the debug it highlights the `matched.offset (0,1)=y (i) ` this line. And also specially before this error occurs it displayed me another vba  error variables are not defined and highlighted `matched` so I defined matched as variant is that the issue so??